# Playing Sequentially audio files (Ionic 3 Native Audio)

Tags: typescript, audio, ionic-framework

I need to play a list of audio files one after another in Ionic 3

and i'm using [ionic native audio plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/)

For information here are how they tell to use the plugin (Official documentation)

```
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio';

constructor(private nativeAudio: NativeAudio) { }

...

this.nativeAudio.preloadSimple('uniqueId1', 'path/to/file.mp3').then(onSuccess, onError);
this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex('uniqueId2', 'path/to/file2.mp3', 1, 1, 0).then(onSuccess, onError);

this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess, onError);

// can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));

this.nativeAudio.loop('uniqueId2').then(onSuccess, onError);

this.nativeAudio.setVolumeForComplexAsset('uniqueId2', 0.6).then(onSuccess,onError);

this.nativeAudio.unload('uniqueId1').then(onSuccess,onError);...
```

And i'm using it in my application in below

```
....
     playAll() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 77; i++) {
          this.playAvecIonNative(i)
        }
      }

    async playAvecIonNative(i) {
        // this.currentBeyit = this.cpt;
        this.idAudio = 'w' + i;
        this.nativeAudio.preloadComplex(this.idAudio, 'assets/audio/' + i + '.ogg', 1, 1, 0)
          .then(await this.onSuccessPreloading, this.onErrorPreload);
      }

      onSuccessPreloading = (data) => {
        this.nativeAudio.play(this.idAudio).then(await this.onSuccessPlaying, this.onErrorPlay);
      }

      onSuccessPlaying = (a) => {
        this.nativeAudio.unload(this.idAudio);
      }

      onErrorPreload() {
        alert('ERREUR PRELOAD')
      }

      onErrorPlay() {
        alert('ERREUR PLAY')
      }
```

When i test with one audio file with the  playAvecIonNative() it works great but for multiple file it doesn't work as expected 
Your expertise would be welcomed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be a bug with the plugin on this level

```
// can optionally pass a callback to be called when the file is done playing
this.nativeAudio.play('uniqueId1', () => console.log('uniqueId1 is done playing'));
```

The bug seems to be on the callback method after the playing is done . The callback is executed at the same time as the this.nativeAudio.play method of the plugin

Check the [Post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/playing-sequentially-audio-files-ionic-3-native-audio/122712)

Comment: Yeah it seems like it considered 'done playing' as loaded and started playing it. I have the same issue and I don't know how to solve it besides running a setTimeout with the play length of the first file on the second; this method is not a good practice.